# Mapping a property to an SQL expression or multiple columns in Fluent nHibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, db2

I have no control over the db schema and need to map two database columns to a single property in my .Net class. The db engine is DB2

The database has columns `AUTH_DT` of type `DATE` and `AUTH_TM` of type `TIME`. The relevant code follows:

```
public class Authorisation{
    ...
    public virtual DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    ...
}
public class AuthorisationMap : ClassMap<Authorisation>{
    ...
    Map(x => x.TransactionDate); //.Column("AUTH_DT" + "AUTH_TM");
    ...
}
```

How can I tell the class-map to combine the date and time columns from the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method called "Formula". This method takes a sql statement that will be mapped to the property. It will be written as a sub query in the sql statement. Used something like this:

```
Map(x => x.TransactionDate).Formula("[[sql statement]]");
```

Comment: Cool. Looks like just what I need. I just need to work out the syntax for my date & time combination now.